# Why does new Date (null, null, null) return valid date in browser?

Tags: javascript, date, browser

I have been checking date function in browser and when run

`new Date (null, null, null);` in dev tool console, it gives valid Date

chrome v 61 return

> Sun Dec 31 1899 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

and firefox DeveloperEdition v 56 return

> Date 1899-12-30T18:30:00.000Z

why so?

P.S.:  also tried `new Date(0,0,0)` and `new Date([],[],[])` and it also behave the same as above and output valid date.

so null is considered as 0 when used in Date object?

someone please explain the behaviour and link to understand this behaviour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [latest drafts of the specs on Date(year, month [ , date ...) ]  constructor](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-date-year-month-date-hours-minutes-seconds-ms), when

> - 2 - assert numberOfArgs ≥ 2
>     [...]
> - 4
>
>   - a - Let y be ? ToNumber(year).
>   - b - Let m be ? ToNumber(month).
>   - c - If date is present, let dt be ? ToNumber(date); else let dt be 1
>       ...

And *ToNumber(all the values you passed)* return `0` yes.

```js
console.log( +null, +0, +[] );
```

Comment: so this is the default value of Date object. but earlier it was 1970 something? when it was changed?

Comment: @pro.mean I didn't now `new Date(0,0,0)` did return unix epoch before, if it ever did; but *1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC* is still used as epoch. `new Date(0,0,0).getTime();` => `-2209107600000`

Comment: Oh and `new Date(0)` does return epoch, because when a single number value is passed, then [timeclip](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-timeclip)  is called.

Comment: yes I have tested and learned that if we provide only 1 argument in `Date()` then it will return epoch time BUT if there are 2 or more argument then it will be manipulated from 1 January 1900 and this is also based on various possibility.

Comment: please look at my gist(https://gist.github.com/zymr-keshav/bee9b9d7ad9fc46da2b90788e88fb79d) based on the learning and one more thing I notice that `new Date("0")` return which can not be retrived by any other way